# Copyright infringement for using a movie poster at a non-commercial conference?

Tags: copyright

I work for an international organization that is organizing a conference that will have around 3,000 people in attendance. To illustrate certain points in our presentation, we wanted to include trailers for certain movies. However, the studios told us that we weren't allowed to use them. Thus, we would like to show the official poster of the movie on our powerpoint presentation. This is a non-commercial conference about work safety and prevention.

Would we get into trouble for using the movie posters?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Copyright is a simple concept, in fact, the concept is built into the name. Copy Right: they have the right to make copies, you don't. Copying *their* poster into *your* presentation is a breach of copyright.

You may be thinking of fair use/fair dealing exemptions to copyright breach. These are tricky and, if you get sued *you* have to demonstrate, at your cost usually, that they apply. Displaying the work in a public venue counts very strongly *against* the defence.

Comment: If you are the owner of a lawful copy of a work (e.g., pictorial or graphic), it is not unlawful to display (or project an image of) that copy anywhere you like, under the "First Sale" doctrine. 17 USC § 109(c). The "public performance" of a motion picture or sound recording would be under different rules and may require a license.